# python findall regex expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I got a long string and i need to find words which contain the character 'd' and afterwards the character 'e'.

```
l=[" xkn59438","yhdck2","eihd39d9","chdsye847","hedle3455","xjhd53e","45da","de37dp"]
b=' '.join(l)
runs1=re.findall(r"\b\w?d.*e\w?\b",b)
print(runs1)
```

\b is the boundary of the word, which follows with any char (\w?) and etc.
I get an empty  list.

Comment: Your strings are only words, why do you need a word boundary anyway?

Comment: Why not apply a regex to each word in the list individually? Why `join` them into a massive string?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Doing re.search i successfully done by making a for loop, just trying to understand how to use re.findall.

Comment: Why are you joining it? This makes your solution that much more complicated, and searching one big strings with a complex regex may end up being worse than searching smaller strings with a simpler regex.

Comment: @coldspeed Yeah i know, i just wanted to understand how to use re.findall, and couldn't grasp why my expression doesn't work. I have already done the same with a for loop for the smaller expression by re.search.

Comment: @david007killer Okay... see my edit?

Comment: @coldspeed Yeah, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can massively simplify your solution by applying a regex based search on each string individually.

```
>>> p = re.compile('d.*e')
>>> list(filter(p.search, l))
```

Or,

```
>>> [x for x in l if p.search(x)]
```

```
['chdsye847', 'hedle3455', 'xjhd53e', 'de37dp']
```

---

Why didn't `re.findall` work? You were searching one large string, and your greedy match in the middle was searching across strings. The fix would've been

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b\S*d\S*e\S*", ' '.join(l))
['chdsye847', 'hedle3455', 'xjhd53e', 'de37dp']
```

Using `\S` to match anything that is not a space.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

`\b\w*d\w*e\w*`

Note that you can probably remove the word boundary here because
the first `\w` guarantees a word boundary before.

The same `\w*d\w*e\w*`

Comment: Thank you, can you explain please why my expression didn't fulfill the same?

Comment: @david007killer Because it was wrong? And why are you insisting on joining the strings? Is there some secret requirement here that you've decided not to mention inyour answer?

Comment: Your regex has this part `.*` which will match non-words and is also greedy. Where as this regex will limit the chars to words only. This would be considered a _pure_ answer unencumbered by whether it's a string or a variable.

Comment: @coldspeed I have answered your question above, and i'm sorry i didn't clarify properly my intentions .

Comment: @sln Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the result :

```
import re
l=[" xkn59438","yhdck2","eihd39d9","chdsye847","hedle3455","xjhd53e","45da","de37dp"]

pattern = r'd.*?e'

print(list(filter(lambda x:re.search(pattern,x),l)))
```

output:

```
['chdsye847', 'hedle3455', 'xjhd53e', 'de37dp']
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802103/4909087), but uglier and less efficient. Having a non-greedy capture group makes no difference on strings this small.

Comment: Thank you for comment bro, I just tried my approach because i wanted to help, But if you don't like I can delete :)